How to mitigate bloat metaspace with Lombok's @Tostring and @EqualsAndHashCode
Background

I am developing an application that has so many DTOs. These DTOs are used in the resultType of MyBatis. This application has so many SQLs.
Each DTO has many (20-100) fields because the application has read/write to legacy-designed DB tables. We cannot modify table designs (it is beyond the scope of this development).
These DTOs use @Getter, @Setter, @Tostring, and @EqualsAndHashCode annotations of Lombok to reduce boilerplate code.

Problem

This application is huge and uses so much metaspace. Because of resource capacity, I want to reduce the usage of metaspace. According to the result of an investigation of Java metaspace, these DTOs consume more than half of metaspace.
According to Lombok's document, the code generated by @Tostring and @EqualsAndHashCode annotations will scale with the number of fields.

Question
Is there any way to mitigate bloat metaspace with Lombok's @Tostring and @EqualsAndHashCode annotations?

Do you really need toString() methods for DTOs? Have you tried just removing the @ToString annotations? Does your application still work? Does the metaspace usage decrease?

What do you mean by "bloat"? It sounds like you have a lot of classes. That is your bloat. Your application is fat. Trim it down. Or tune the MetaspaceSize and MaxMetaspaceSize so your application fits.

A reflection-based implementation comes with a ton of headache which is why lombok doesn't do it. But, your toString, hashCode, and equals impls all turn into one-liners. I rather doubt you're barking up the right tree (that your app is falling over under the weight of a bajillion humongous DTO classes - okay, yes, sure, you figured that out. "Lets reduce the size of the toString code" doesn't strike me as the correct thought as to how to get away from the problems you have, though! - but if  you must, that would help. I'm not sure its right to answer this question by suggesting this, though.

I also suggest to check if you really need all the DTO fields to be included in the equals, hashCode and toString generated method, by configuring Lombok annotations. Anyway, as @Sören suggested, it is a good idea to check how much metaspace occupation changes when removing the Lombok methods, or keeping just one of the two, to understand if they really impact and how much.

Separately, there's the perennial 'DTOs / JPA is confused about what it is modelling' issue. Say, you have class Person that is a DTO. What does it represent? Does it represent 'a person', or, 'a row in a database table that represents a person'? Sounds the same but those two things are opposites as far as equals/hashCode is concerned. One implies the primary keys are the only thing that matter for equals/hashCode, the other implies (assuming an auto-count/uuid primary key) that everything except the primary keys matter.

I don't use hibernate and this is one of the reasons; tools that cannot explain themselves using a consistent model sound like tools I don't wanna use, but if you must, you need to answer that question. I believe the most sensible thing is to treat a DTO as 'models a row in a DB' in which case your equals/hashcode should cover only the primary key, which makes the equals/hashCode methods a lot smaller.
